# 404 error on running the spring mvc application

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a simple spring mvc, security and tiles application which is working, but it was not loading css and js file. I have added `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` in `*-servlet.xml` file. In source I could see that JS and css are getting loaded but, actual application is giving 404 error.

**[image: Project Structure]**

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Security Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml** 
Please Note that If I remove "" from mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, it is working fine but css and js files are not loading.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <!-- <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean> -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/config/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant open you project structure. but is `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*" />` correct? I assume you copiedt his project from mykong's blog.

Comment: yes, that is correct, I think there is some problem with URL pattern, I'm notable to figure out.

Comment: If I don't use " <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />" it works, I mean it will redirect to login page. I will update with controller and security code.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` element in order to use `<mvc:resources>`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

The `annotation-driven` configuration bootstraps the controller model, and adding `mvc:resource` is like adding a special kind of controller that deals with static resources.